# How to use state variable for conditional declaring of array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-statements, use-state

In React js, What I want to do is: declare an array of objects (routes) and export.
For conditional declaration of array of objects, I want to use an state variable (which returns whether user logged in or not).

Aim:

- user logged in, show `Put Rating` option
- user not logged in, dont show `Put Rating` option.

*The file of array of objects which I have to export for mapping*

```
import {AppState} from '../AppContext';

function IsLoggedIn(){
   const {user} = AppState();
   return user===null;
}

const routes=[
  {
    title:"home page",
    show:true,
  },
  {
    title:"put rating",
    show: IsLoggedIn(),
  }
];

export default routes;
```

It returns error like hooks can only be used inside body of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your AppState to a context/reducer so that whenever a user authenticates we can properly react to this state change then

```
const routes=[
  {
    title:"home page",
    private:false,
  },
  {
    title:"put rating",
    private:true,
  }
];
```

Create a separate component called `PrivateWrapper` or anything you like and inside that put this logic

```
export default function PrivateWrapper(props){
    const {user} = AppState();
    return !user ? null : props.children;
}
```

Finally when looping through the routes array just check if private is true then wrap the element with PrivateWrapper

```
routes.map(route =>(
route.private ? 
<PrivateWrapper>{route.title}</PrivateWrapper> : route.title
))
```

You can also use this wrapper with any element you want.